# IE9 bug in css background-repeat with display inline elements

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, background-repeat

I tried to apply a background with no-repeat set to "inline" elements, on IE9, if the text spans more than one line the image appears on all lines, did anyone face this problem yet? does anyone have a solution?

```
.text {background: url(../images/ibullet.png) no-repeat left top;
    display: inline; /* or inline-block */
     }

<span class="text">try me on multiple lines</span>
```

Comment: there is a typo in your code, it should be: background: url(../images/ibullet.png) no-repeat left top; (remove the last bracket)

Comment: err, ignore that typo, i just wrote it from sratch here, but the bug is still valid :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE9 isn't final yet, the release candidate was outed today.  If you think there is a bug, then the solution is to report it so that it can be fixed for the final release.

It's not advised to use work arounds in pre-release builds of browsers.  You can report the bug by clicking the *Tools* (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>) -> *Send Feedback*.